# how do you fix this error Can only concatenate list (not"float") to list

Tags: python-2.7

```
def Combat(player,Enemy):
userInput = input("How would you like to attack the enemy (P)ower attack, (Q)uick Attack,(C)ounter attack, or (N)ormal attack?").upper()
PlayerAttackRoll = [random.randint(1,20)-1]
EnemyAttackRoll = [random.randint(1,20)-1]
PlayerAttackBonus = player['Attack'] / 5
EnemyAttackBonus = Enemy['Attack'] / 5
PlayerDefenseBonus = player['Defense'] /5
EnemyDefenseBonus = Enemy['Defense'] / 5
if userInput == "P":
    PlayerAttackBonus *= 2
    EnemyAttackBonus *= 1.5
elif userInput =="Q":
    PlayerAttackBonus *= 2
    EnemyDefenseBonus *= 1.5
elif userInput =="C":
    PlayerAttackBonus *= 2.5
    PlayerAttackBonus *= 0
elif userInput =="N":
    player['Attack']
while True:# This is where i keep getting the error at
    PlayerDamage = PlayerAttackRoll + PlayerAttackBonus - EnemyDefenseBonus -10
    EnemyDamage = EnemyAttackRoll + EnemyAttackBonus - PlayerDefenseBonus - 10
    if PlayerDamage == "<=0":
           print("You have missed Enemy took no damage.")
    elif EnemyDamage == "<=0":
        print("Enemy has missed you take no damage.")
return player,Enemy
```

*I am making a little game but i keep getting this error
PlayerDamage=PlayerAttackRoll + PlayerAttackBonus - EnemyDefenseBonus - 10
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "float") to list
Can someone help me fix this please.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PlayerAttackRoll is a list so when you are doing

```
PlayerAttackRoll + PlayerAttackBonus
```

It is trying to perform list concatenation.

Either

```
PlayerAttackRoll = random.randint(1,20)-1
```

or

```
PlayerAttackRoll = [random.randint(1,20)-1][0]
```

should work.

Although, you really don't need to initialize it as a list since it is a single value. Same thing with EnemyAttackRoll.